# Navigate to an instance of a page

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my project I got a page NotePage.xaml
it has a textbox named TextBoxTitle and a textbox named TextBoxTheNote.

In the code-behind of another page, I make an instance of this page and fill in both textboxes.
What I can't seem to figure out is: how do I navigate to that instance?

I don't have any kind of uri or anything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why dont you call the page using a uri passing as parameter the text to fill the textboxes with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With windows phone you don't create an instance of a page and navigate to it. You just navigate to the page you need and pass in the values through a series of different methods.

First navigations

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("YourXamlPageName.Xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Now that we have you navigating here comes the fun part.

Deciding how you want to pass your data.

There are a number of ways.

First you can embed it in the URI

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("YourXamlPageName.Xaml?pageTitle=Whatever", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Then retrieve it in the navigated to of the other page

You can also serialize your data and retrive it on the other side.

You can use the EZ_Iso.dll for this. Very simple and fast. Great for complex objects
http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Finally another method of passing data is through the Phone Application Service dictionary
Outlined here in this blog post

http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=10

Which ever way you choose just make sure to be consistent so it keeps your code clean.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, this feels like I found a missing link :)

Comment: Make sure to upvote and checkmark if this answer solves the problem